# Trying to use StageXl library in dart failing

Tags: dart, stagexl

my *main.dart* file looks like this:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:stagexl/stagexl.dart' as stageXL;

void main() {
  CanvasElement canvas = querySelector("#canvas");
  stageXL.Stage stage = new stageXL.Stage(canvas, width: 300, height: 400);
  stageXL.RenderLoop renderLoop = new stageXL.RenderLoop();
  renderLoop.addStage(stage);
}
```

but after `pub serve` and running index.html in dartium i get

```
Internal error: 'package:stagexl/src/events/event_dispatcher.dart': error: 
line 43 pos 20: unexpected token '<'
EventStream<T> on<T extends Event>(String eventType) {
                 ^
```

error. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Dartium?

Comment: You need at least Dart 1.24.0 or use an older version of StageXL